# Indirect modification of overloaded property App\Models\frontend\Document::$selfie has no effect

Tags: laravel

This is a frequently asked question here, but it's the first time I'm encountering this problem And I saw other questions but I could not solve my problem. As far as I'm concerned I'm copying Laravel's documentation exactly, but I'm getting this error. I assume it's to do with the sub-relationships between models. Of course, I'm not sure
What do you think is the problem?

my controller :

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Frontend;

use App\Models\frontend\Document as DocumentModel;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class Document extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $selfie;
    public $id_card;
    public $tc_agree;
    public $currect_information;

    public function sendDocument()
    {
        if ($document = auth()->user()->Document()->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->first()) {
            $doc = DocumentModel::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first();

            if ($document->selfie['status'] !== 'accepted' && $document->selfie['status'][0] !== 'pending') {
                $this->validate([
                    'selfie' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2024',
                    'tc_agree' => 'accepted',
                    'currect_information' => 'accepted',
                ]);

                $selfie_url = $this->selfie->store('documents/'. Crypt::decryptString($document->secret));

                $doc->selfie['url'] = Crypt::encryptString($selfie_url);
                $doc->selfie['status'] = 'pending';
                $doc->selfie['desc'] = '';

                $doc->save();
            }

            if ($document->idcard['status'] != 'accepted' && $document->idcard['status'] != 'pending') {
                $this->validate([
                    'id_card' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2024',
                    'tc_agree' => 'accepted',
                    'currect_information' => 'accepted',
                ]);

                $idcard_card = $this->id_card->store('documents/'. Crypt::decryptString($document->secret));

                $doc->idcard['url'] = Crypt::encryptString($idcard_card);
                $documdocent->idcard['status'] = 'pending';
                $doc->idcard['desc'] = '';

                $doc->save();
            }
        } else {
            $this->validate([
                'selfie' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2024',
                'id_card' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:2024',
                'tc_agree' => 'accepted',
                'currect_information' => 'accepted',
            ]);

            $random = Str::random(35);

            $selfie_url = $this->selfie->store('documents/'.$random);
            $idcard_card = $this->id_card->store('documents/'.$random);

            DocumentModel::updateOrCreate([
                'user_id' => Auth::User()->id,
                'secret' => Crypt::encryptString($random),
                'selfie' => [
                    'url' => Crypt::encryptString($selfie_url),
                    'status' => 'pending',
                    'last_update' => Carbon::now(),
                    'desc' => '',
                ],
                'idcard' => [
                    'url' => Crypt::encryptString($idcard_card),
                    'status' => 'pending',
                   'last_update' => Carbon::now(),
                   'desc' => '',
                ],
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.frontend.document');
    }
}
```

And model:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models\frontend;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Document extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = "document";

    protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'secret',
        'selfie',
        'idcard',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'selfie' => 'array',
        'idcard' => 'array',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Domains\Auth\Models\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: Do this and see what you get `$document = auth()->user()->Document()->where('user_id', Auth::User()->id)->first();``dd($document)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `$doc->selfie` is not writable directly. You are casting `selfie` as an `array` and that is correct, but you cannot replace the value of it like `$doc->selfie['key1'] = 123;`, you have to do:

```php
$doc->selfie = [
    'url' => Crypt::encryptString($selfie_url),
    'status' => 'pending',
    'desc' => ''
];

$doc->save();
```

If I am not confused, that should work, so edit your code wherever you do `$doc->selfie['key'] = something;` with my fix...

**same for `$doc->idcard`...**

---

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) shows you to use my method.

Remember, this is a cast, internally you have a JSON structure and when you do `$doc->selfie` as a `get` action, it will cast it to array, that is why you cannot do `$doc->selfie['key'] = 123;`.